# Session state issue in Kentico site hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, security, kentico

There is an application developed using Kentico 10 and hosted in Azure.

We recently install azure application gateway for this particular site,

In this site there is a function to add and view items to shopping cart.

So after installing the application gateway, the add and view items to shopping cart function won't work properly, Most of the time added items won't display when go to the view cart so its happening randomly, I suspect this is due to some issue on session state synchronization.

Our site URL is map to gateway and from there its goes to a application, and we do not have web farm as well, and session State mode is "InProc"

Since Azure Application Gateway is a web traffic load balancer

1- Does it required to setup a webfarm since we have azure application gateway?

2- Do i need to use "StateServer", "SQLServer" or "Custom" (e.g. Azure Redis Cache) since we have azure application gateway?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not have multiple application connecting to same database, Web Farms are not necessary. However shopping cart is saved in session, cookie and DB and first point of retrieval would be session. Since azure app gateway has its s[ession affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction#session-affinity) you could try using that.

In case this does not help, you will need to use other storage (I believe redis cache to be the fastest), but point would be to better tie user with session.